# Which function does dynamic binding call?

Tags: java, dynamic, overriding

What is the value of `a.x`?

I think dynamic binding choses the `g()` function in the superclass because `super.f()` is called. Or am I wrong and does dynamic binding call the override function of `g()` so the result becomes 27? If so, why?

[image: dynamic binding exercise]

Comment: Have you just tried running this code?

Comment: @StephaneM I see it's 27 but I don't understand why.

Comment: @Michiel What do you mean exactly by "why"? It is the semantics of Java. It is just defined this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've modified your code to trace what's going on:

```
public class A {
    public void f() { System.out.println("A.f");x = x + 4; g();System.out.println(this); }
    public void g() { System.out.println("A.g");x = x + 10;}
    public int x = 5;
    }


public class B extends A {
    @Override public void f() { System.out.println("B.f");x = x + 3; super.f(); }
    @Override public void g() { System.out.println("B.g");x = x + 15; }
}
```

The output is:

```
B.f
A.f
B.g
com.sandbox.Main$B@18fb53f6
27
```

When g() is called from A, you can see `this` is actually a B object, that's why the g() method from B is invoked.

Answer (score 0):

All instance methods in java are virtual, so `B.g()` is called and the answer is `27`.